# How make Discord bot post messages than were provided by user?

Tags: javascript, axios, discord.js, bots

I have a very simple React application, Discord bot, and Node.js server.

I want that the text that user is typing in the front application, will be sent by the Discord bot in the Discord channel.

So, if user is typing "`hello world`" and submit by clicking the button, the Discord bot should type "`hello world`" in the channel.

FRONT:

```js
function App() {

  const [input, setinput] = useState('')
  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={(e) => setinput(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button onClick={() => axios.post('http://localhost:8080/post', { post: input })} >   push me</button>

    </>
  )
}
```

BOT && BACK [only the relevant parts]:

```js
app.post('/pass', async (req, res) => {
    post = req.body.post})
    


client.on('messageCreate', msg => {

    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.reply(`${post}`);
     }

})
```

This code is working.
`post` is the text that user typed, but it is presented only on certain conditions (user typed a message '`ping`' on Discord)

But how I do the same thing unconditionally, making my bot post a message every time user submits this message on the frontend?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In addition to your own answer, I suggest that you a) be consistent with formatting in your arrow functions. For example, in the first arrow function shown in your backend, the closing braces are not on their own line, but in the second one they are, and separated by an extra line. In addition, b) place semicolons at the end of the arrow functions for readability. This is not as bad and it's different for every developer, but if it doesn't end in a comma or a curly brace `{}`, and doesn't have any extra methods, like `.then()` or `.catch()`, then it could use a semicolon at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

I found way to do that with Discord webhooks:

```js
app.post('/pass', async (req, res) => {
    post = req.body.post
    
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(`${post}`)
        .setColor(0x00FFFF);

    webhookClient.send({
        content: '',
        username: 'Mighty John Silver',
        avatarURL: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTLHezDv-KefVm8icZAoVxZOJAsICm2gB5QKg&usqp=CAU',
        embeds: [embed],
    });
})
```